# MimeType via Java Apache tika

Tags: java, mime-types, apache-tika

I have a problem with file determination.

On developer server and on production servers `Apache tika` determine all kind of files. But on test server  most time I got :

> 'application/octet-stream'

```
public static String detectMimeType(final File file) throws IOException {
        TikaInputStream tikaIS = null;
        try {
            tikaIS = TikaInputStream.get(file);
            final Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            return DETECTOR.detect(tikaIS, metadata).toString();
        } finally {
            if (tikaIS != null) {
                tikaIS.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't understand the problem. Please help.

Comment: yep thanks that's `octet-stream`

Comment: Do you have all the Tika jars present? And do you have the full tika mimetypes file on your classpath? And the same (latest) version of Tika everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

application/octet-stream is the fallback if no more specific mimetype could be detected. It simply means that your file is just a series of octets or bytes.